# How to get Windows Remote Management (WinRM) version?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 4.0.

From the `get-help about_Remote_Requirements`:

> To run remote sessions on Windows PowerShell 3.0, the local and remote
>   computers
>       must have the following:
>
> ```
>     --  Windows PowerShell 3.0 or later
>     --  The Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 or later
>     --  Windows Remote Management 3.0
> ```

How can I get the *Windows Remote Management* (WinRM) version? I don't see this info in the output of the `$PSVersionTable` variable:

[image]

**UPD**

The `winrm id` result:

[image]

Comment: `winrm id` see the Stack version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If WinRM is Running:

`winrm id' Check the Stack Version

If WinRM is Not Running, check the Version number for `%Windir%\System32\wsmsvc.dll`

```
(Get-Item C:\Windows\System32\wsmsvc.dll).VersionInfo.FileVersion
```

Or: `$PSVersionTable.BuildVersion.ToString()` (Has the same result)

if it can help you, This will work until version 2

```
Function Get-WinRMVersion
{
    $WinRM = ((Get-Item C:\Windows\System32\wsmsvc.dll).VersionInfo.FileVersion -Split '\s')[0]
    Switch -Wildcard ($WinRM)
    {
    "5.2.3790.2075" {0.5}
    "6.0.6000.16386" {1.0}
    "5.1.2600.3191" {1.1}
    "5.2.3790.2990" {1.1}
    "5.2.3790.4131" {1.1}
    "6.0.6001.18000" {2.0}
    "6.1.7600.16385" {2.0}
    "6.2.*" {return "Greater then v2"}
    }
}
```